# React-Native SVG background

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

I'm trying to get a background pattern using an SVG in React-Native.

I have created an Component using 'react-native-svg' library as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { SvgXml } from "react-native-svg";

const xml = `
  <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
    <g
      fill='#ffb6c1'
      fill-opacity='0.2'
    >
      <polygon 
        fill-rule='evenodd'
        points='8 4 12 6 8 8 6 12 4 8 0 6 4 4 6 0 8 4'
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
`;

export default () => <SvgXml xml={xml}  />;
```

I then tried to import it into App.js as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header'
import SVG from './assets/4-point-star'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View  style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground source={{uri: SVG}} style={styles.image}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    color: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
},
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white'
  },
});
```

However, I get the following error on the device:
[image]

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ImageBackground (which inherits Image props) [doesn't support](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/react-native/image/#source) components or anything other than what would be an image file.
**So you have to use the SVG component directly and style it.**
*You can also convert the SVG directly to a component with the online tool [svgr](https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true).*

Assuming you make it a component to receive parameters (like svgr makes) you can use it as a (full size) background like:

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
    
...
<>
    ...
    <SVG width={width} height={height} style={{ zIndex: -1, elevation: -1 }} />
    <View>
        ...
    </View>
</>
```

Or just edit height/width as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I've discovered it happens when I run my app on web and change the view to Iphone. I'm using expo so I read the QR code with the app Expo Go and I see it perfectly. I looked everywhere and my code seemed right, i returned my SVG as a component as someone said before.